# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package

Tags: python, http, server, simplehttprequesthandler

I am trying to setup http server on my machine but I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package
```

I have 2 files in my project directory: `http.py` and `index.html`.

Here is the `http.py`:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8080
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

I have already tried changing module to `BaseHTTPServer` and I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'
```

I also notice a weird thing happen on my terminal. If I try do

```
python3 -m pip uninstall <module>
```

I get an error such as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'http.server'; 'http' is not a package
```

which is throwing me off because I am not even running the file. I mention this in case it is any indication that some local configuration might be the problem of all.

Comment: I can run the above code in a script. How are you interacting with the snippet shared above? [http](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/http.server.html) is part of the standard library so you can't `pip` uninstall it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have 2 files in dir > http.py and index.html. Curiously I was able to make it work one way but not by running my main file. I can make it work by doing ```python3``` to enter py and do it line by line but I have to import http first or else I get the attribute error. However I tried to do 
```import http
import http.server```
in my main py file but it still gives me the attr error.

Comment: The fact that your file is called `http.py` is the problem.

Comment: This is an important detail that should be part of the question: **I have 2 files in dir > http.py and index.html**. Consider sharing the error stack trace as well.

Comment: @chx if you found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61494575/7695722) useful, kindly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: this fixed it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have named your file as `http.py`. This is overriding the standard library [http](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html) module. To solve:

- You have to rename the file `http.py` to something else.
- Remove `.pyc` files in the project

  `find . -name "*.pyc" -delete`
- Run the program again.

It may interest you to read up on how [modules and packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) work in Python.